# Project nested array field values by their indexes in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm doing an aggregation in **MongoDB** which should have an array fields projection in its `$project` stage . But I can't access array fields by their indexes :

```
{//projection stage
  $project: {
    'foo' : { '$ifNull' : ['$bar.0.baz.0.qux', '*'] }
  }
}
```

This sets `foo` to an empty **array** . bar is a multidimensional array field. my MongoDB version is 3.2 . What can I do for this without the hassle of `$unwind/$group` old heavy solution ?

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/), [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```js
{ "$project": {
    "foo": {
        "$ifNull": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": { "$slice": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": { "$slice": [ "$bar", 0, 1 ] },
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": "$$el.baz"
                        }},
                        0, 1
                    ]},
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$el.qux", 0 ] }
                 }},
                 0
             ]},
            "*"
        ]
    }
}}
```

So the inner `$map` operators allow you to just select the particular fields out of each array, which you can `$slice` at the desired position to just return that element. i.e `0,1` is zero index and just one element.

The for the final resulting array you just use `$arrayElemAt` and retrieve the indexed element turning it into a single value.

Of course the `$ifNull` tests might need to be more involved depending on your structure, as if it's not consistent then you probably need to check each `$map` input and swap with a result accordingly.

But the general process is :

- `$map` to get fields
- `$slice` to reduce arrays from `$map`
- `$arrayElemAt` on the final array result.

---

On something like this:

```js
  db.foo.insert({
    "bar": [
      { 
        "baz": [
          { "qux": 2 },
          { "qux": 5 }
        ]
      },
      {
        "baz": [
          { "qux": 3 },
          { "qux": 4 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
```

Produces:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e8c6b8ff2a05c0da90b31e"), "foo" : 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks man . I'm trying to understand this solution. It seems to work well . I'll check your answer soon . its sad that they haven't replaced this giant code snippet with simple javascript object access pattern. Hope to see that in future releases.

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple $project stage with $arrayElemAt operator with temporary fields.

`{$project:{"tmp": {$arrayElemAt:["$bar",0]}}},
{$project:{"tmp2": {$arrayElemAt:["$tmp.baz",0]}}}`

than your value is at $tmp2.qux.